# how to create ip alias in nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, ubuntu, requestjs

I am writing test in nodejs.
Calling my api using requestjs.
Now I have to make one call  using an ip address to the api (/resources/media)
Then I have to make another call to the same api (/resources/media) using different ip from the same computer.

OS: ubuntu

any idea how to do that
help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add another ip and make sure it was not existed before

sudo ip addr add 192.168.50.5 dev eth1

Then user localAddress option in requestjs

Answer (score 0):

Your only choice is to [set up a proxy](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/squid/squid-http-proxy-ubuntu-12-04) (like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)), bind it to another (virtual) networking interface card and [make the second request through it](https://github.com/request/request#proxies).